# How do I use browser fingerprint in my website?

Tags: angular, api, security, browser, browser-detection

I want to identify users accessing my API even if they clear the `cookies` or `localstorage` wherever I am storing the current session information. I see that `browser fingerprinting` is one of the ways to achieve this up to some accuracy. I am working on an `angular2` project for the frontend. I have the following questions:

1. Are there any libraries available for angular2 which creates the browser fingerprint? (I have seen [ng2-device-detector](https://github.com/KoderLabs/ng2-device-detector). This doesn't give much info and also no hashed fingerprint. So, do I have to hash it myself? )
2. Have seen [fingerprintjs2](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2) this does take a lot of info but has no implementation for `angular2`, but I wonder how would the hashed fingerprint actually matter? For a Request in my API, I will check if the payload contained a `fingerprint` which already existed in any of the existing sessions? (Really payload? It will just be a `POST` request. The user can simply send a random long string as the hashed `fingerprint` and the API will treat the request as if it came from a different person.)
3. I guess then I will have to use some API which not only generates a `hashed fingerprint` in the `frontend` but also validates after the request has reached the API, something like `Google's reCaptcha`. Are there any APIs like such?
4. If there aren't any APIs as such then I guess I will have to implement such functionality in my API itself?

Please write your suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

**1.** It seems there **isn't** any library(ported or otherwise) especially for **Angular2**.

**2.** You don't need an Angular2 version of it, just inject the source file in your **index.html** and you can use it like this, [**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/b0UYaOpjskJr1UzDe5W2?p=preview)

```ts
declare var Fingerprint2: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `Hello`,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components){
      console.log(result); // a hash, representing your device fingerprint
      console.log(components); // an array of FP components
    });
  }
}
```

You have to treat this **hash** as any other token like `JWT`, exclusively or inclusively. But you do need to store it somewhere, just like any other token, that's how you will be able check it's authenticity. If a user tempers with the request and hash, JWT has a validation mechanism that makes it invalid on tampering, but I suppose fingerprinting hash can't provide that safety.

**3.** No, none (IMK).

**4.** If **no.-2** works for you I suppose you'll be far better off.

Comment: Instead of 'declare var...' you should use the full typings from here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/fingerprintjs2

Comment: Thanks, @Ankit Singh, after your answer I stopped looking for ways in which I can validate the fingerprint. My requirement was to identify an intruder(who could definitely try out with random fingerprints). Using `fingerprintjs2` will definitely be useful for identifying a normal user.

Comment: @Ludwig can you please explain a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Ankit pretty much answered in relation to Angular. Here is an API that provides a fingerprint so you do not need to implement it yourself:

[Browser Fingerprint API](http://www.devpowerapi.com/)

Although this solution is not an Angular component (or what-have-you), you can make an AJAX call to get the fingerprint and submit it to your server.

Full Disclosure: I am the developer of this service.

Comment: Yes he did, I will have a look at this API but I believe this will be similar to using https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2

Comment: @AshishRanjan- It is a bit different from FingerprintJS. You don't need to include a JS file or call a JS function, so the integration is simpler. However, since the service is API based it is not as accurate as Fingerprint JS.